# .NET Web API 2 OWIN Bearer Token Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm implementing a Web API 2 service architecture in my .NET web application.  The client consuming the requests is pure javascript, no mvc/asp.net.  I'm using OWIN to try to enable token authentication per this article [OWIN Bearer Token Authentication with Web API Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-Bearer-Token-d5eeecc2).  I seem to be missing something with the authentication step after its authorized.

My login looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/account/login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginBindingModel login)
    {
        // todo: add auth
        if (login.UserName == "a@a.com" && login.Password == "a")
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, login.UserName));

            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
            var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
            ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
            ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

            DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken); 

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ObjectContent<object>(new  
                { 
                    UserName = login.UserName,
                    AccessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket)
                }, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter)
            };
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

It returns

```
{
   accessToken: "TsJW9rh1ZgU9CjVWZd_3a855Gmjy6vbkit4yQ8EcBNU1-pSzNA_-_iLuKP3Uw88rSUmjQ7HotkLc78ADh3UHA3o7zd2Ne2PZilG4t3KdldjjO41GEQubG2NsM3ZBHW7uZI8VMDSGEce8rYuqj1XQbZzVv90zjOs4nFngCHHeN3PowR6cDUd8yr3VBLdZnXOYjiiuCF3_XlHGgrxUogkBSQ",
   userName: "a@a.com"
}
```

Then I try to set the HTTP header `Bearer` on further requests in AngularJS like:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Bearer = response.accessToken;
```

to a API like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/account/profile")]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage Profile()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<object>(new
            {
                UserName = User.Identity.Name
            }, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter)
        };
    }
```

but no matter what I do this service is 'unauthorized'.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: The article link you provided shows a page stating 'This item is not yet published.'. I am very interested in enabling web api authorization with a bearer token. Can you please provide any resources or an updated link to the article you used? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, in your code I cannot see how you generated the access token! Could you please clarify it?

Comment: @s0nica .net does that automatically with owin

Comment: Ok but I cannot see where and how you defined and assigned a value to the variable `accessToken`

Comment: @likestoski I believe this was the article, or the article that replaced it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx

Comment: Hi, im dealing with similar stuff but with MVC 4 using Controller (not ApiController) but almost the same and I dont know how to create a manual authetnication. Because I can't use Forms Authentication because It will redirect my URL like ASP.MVC does. Any clue? Thanks a lot

Comment: @amcdnl - where do you get accessToken from? in the line. DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

Comment: @PeterStulinski - I wrote a gist that contains all the code I used for my implementation: https://gist.github.com/amcdnl/8239023

Comment: Actually I was looking on "how to pass a bearer token if you login with the classic MVC form" and you give me the answer! :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Resolved by setting header 'Authorization' with Bearer + token like:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token.accessToken;
```

Comment: a question: how do you store the access token to avoid re-authentication? Do you store it in a cookie or something?

Comment: @Blaise - Yes ASP.NET sets it automatically on the return.

Comment: @Blaise if you're using the SPA template provided in VS2013, the token is stored in sessionStorage or localStorage. The ".AspNet.Cookies" cookie is for cookie authentication if you have both enabled. If you don't explicitly tell Web API to ignore cookie authentication (which is done for you in the SPA template) then it will still authenticate using said cookie, regardless of whether or not you pass along the bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it with your angular application module. So authorization token will be set as header for every http request.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
app.run(function ($http) {

     $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token.accessToken;

});
```