# Web API 2 OWIN Bearer token authentication - AccessTokenFormat null?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I'm adding a Web API 2 project to it. I want to use bearer token authentication and have followed Hongye Sun's tutorial "OWIN Bearer Token Authentication with Web API Sample" and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769422/net-web-api-2-owin-bearer-token-authentication) as well.

In my `Login` method, for the line `Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);`, the **AccessTokenFormat** is null. Any idea why?

My **AccountController**:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{        
    public AccountController() {}

    // POST api/login
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(int id, string pwd)
    {
        if (id > 0) // testing - not authenticating right now
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, id.ToString()));
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
            var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
            ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
            ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            var token = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ObjectContent<object>(new
                {
                    UserName = id.ToString(),
                    AccessToken = token
                }, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter)
            };
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    // POST api/token
    [Route("token")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Token(int id, string pwd)
    {
        // Never reaches here. Do I need this method?
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

**Startup** class:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private static readonly ILog _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
    public static Func<MyUserManager> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "MyWeb";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new MyUserManager(new UserStore<MyIdentityUser>());

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            Provider = new MyWebOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/login"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {         
        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/api/login")
        });

        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;            
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType));

        app.UseWebApi(config);                          
    }
}
```

**MyIdentityUser** just adds an extra property:

```cs
public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int SecurityLevel { get; set; }
}
```

**MyUserManager** calls my custom user authentication method to an internal server:

```cs
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<MyIdentityUser>
{
    public MyUserManager(IUserStore<MyIdentityUser> store) : base(store) { }

    public MyIdentityUser ValidateUser(int id, string pwd)
    {
        LoginIdentityUser user = null;

        if (MyApplication.ValidateUser(id, pwd))
        {
            // user = ??? - not yet implemented
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

**MyWebOAuthProvider** (I took this from the SPA template. Only `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` has been changed):

```cs
public class MyWebOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;
    private readonly Func<MyUserManager> _userManagerFactory;

    public MyWebOAuthProvider(string publicClientId, Func<MyUserManager> userManagerFactory)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        if (userManagerFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userManagerFactory");
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
        _userManagerFactory = userManagerFactory;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (MyUserManager userManager = _userManagerFactory())
        {
            MyIdentityUser user = null;
            var ctx = context as MyWebOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext;

            if (ctx != null)
            {
                user = userManager.ValidateUser(ctx.Id, ctx.Pwd);
            }                

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        ...  // unchanged from SPA template
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        ...  // unchanged from SPA template
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        ...  // unchanged from SPA template
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
    {
        ...  // unchanged from SPA template
    }
}
```

**MyWebOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredientialsContext**:

```cs
public class MyWebOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext : OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext
{
    public MyWebOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext (IOwinContext context, OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options, string clientId, string userName, string password, IList<string> scope)
        : base(context, options, clientId, userName, password, scope)
    { }

    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Pwd { get; set; }
}
```

How is **AccessTokenFormat** set? Is what I've set up correct? I'm not authenticating against any external services, just a legacy internal server.
Thanks.

Comment: The link "OWIN Bearer Token Authentication with Web API Sample" seems *broken*. It says "This item is not yet published."

Comment: @kr85 I removed the link. If you look at Hongye Sun's answer below, you'll see that he removed that code sample as it caused confusion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem - it was to do with my initialisation in Startup().

Like you, I was storing the OAuthBearerOptions in a static field:

```
OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
```

But then I was wrongly using a *new instance* of the same class later on:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());  // wrong!
```

Obviously the fix was to use the static field instead:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

In fact, it doesn't look like you call UseOAuthBearerAuthentication() at all.  I followed this [excellent series of posts](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) by Taiseer Joudeh.

Full Startup.cs:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {

            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()  // see post
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

        //[Configure External Logins...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for the answer to this - but here's a bit of code that I'm using in my AngularJS app to get the security token from my WebAPI2 endpoint.

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST', url: '/token', data: { username: uName, password: uPassword, grant_type: 'password' },
        transformRequest: function (obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("http success", data);
        accessToken.value = data.access_token;
        console.log("access token = ", accessToken.value);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("http error", data);
    });
```

I can then pass the accessToken in the header of any other requests in order to get the authentication validation.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the sample code as it can cause confusion when it's used with Web API and SPA template. You'd better stay with the template code to use OAuth authorization server to generate token. In your scenario, you should use resource owner password grant to authenticate the user. Please check my blog on SPA template which has details about the password flow on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx

Instead of writing your own Web API to handle login, you need to use OWIN OAuth Server's /token endpoint to handle password login.

Comment: Thanks for responding. If I just need to authenticate the user using an internal legacy server application and not any external OAuth providers, do I still need to set **AuthorizeEndpointPath**? If so, what should I set it to? Should my authentication calls be placed in an override of `userManager.FindAsync()`? Is there an example of this somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: @Ionian316 I must admit i am trying to do the same thing but there is almost no documentation? did you ever get this right?

Comment: @StevenYates No, I ended up going back and using my old custom `MembershipProvider` class to handle authentication, instead of using OAuth and tokens. Don't know if Web API 2.1 has improved things much or not. I might take another look when Web API 3 comes out. Hope they will improve things by then.

Comment: @PeterStulinski No, see my comments to Steven above.