# What's the default OAuth AccessTokenFormat implementation in OWIN for IIS host?

Tags: c#, oauth, owin, bearer-token

[Web API 2 OWIN Bearer token authentication - AccessTokenFormat null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938947/web-api-2-owin-bearer-token-authentication-accesstokenformat-null)

The default /Token endpoints works fine and I could get token from there,
but I need to use the AccessTokenFormat.Protect method on a ticket to generate accessToken for externalLogin.

Basically my implementation is pretty much the same as this one, and I encountered the same problem of the AccessTokenFormat is null.
From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserveroptions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) it says:

> The data format used to protect the information contained in the access token. If not provided by the application the default data protection provider depends on the host server. The SystemWeb host on IIS will use ASP.NET machine key data protection, and HttpListener and other self-hosted servers will use DPAPI data protection. If a different access token provider or format is assigned, a compatible instance must be assigned to the OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.AccessTokenProvider or OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.AccessTokenFormat property of the resource server.

It looks to me that if the AccessTokenFormat is not assigned, the host would provide a basic implementation for it. But I don't see it works here.
Is there a way I could find the default implementation of the ISecureDataFormatAccessTokenFormat and assign it to the variable manually?

Or does anyone have other ideas how to solves this?

UPDATE:
I get the source code for katana and find the OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware class, from the source code I could see the following code:

```
if (Options.AccessTokenFormat == null)
        {
            IDataProtector dataProtecter = app.CreateDataProtector(
                typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
                "Access_Token", "v1");
            Options.AccessTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtecter);
        }
```

In my Startup.Auth, here is my code:

```
     static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat = OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenProvider = OAuthOptions.AccessTokenProvider;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationMode = OAuthOptions.AuthenticationMode;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType = OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType;
        OAuthBearerOptions.Description = OAuthOptions.Description;

        OAuthBearerOptions.Provider = new CustomBearerAuthenticationProvider();
        OAuthBearerOptions.SystemClock = OAuthOptions.SystemClock;
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);


        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

}

I also have the following in WebApiConfig

```
// Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

I'm not sure why 
`app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);` is not setting the accessTokenFormat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not setting it correctly, but I pull out the code and assign to it my self. Here's my final working code looks like:

```
      public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);


        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AccessTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(app.CreateDataProtector(
               typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
               "Access_Token", "v1")),
            RefreshTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(app.CreateDataProtector(
                typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
                "Refresh_Token", "v1")),
            AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat = OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenProvider = OAuthOptions.AccessTokenProvider;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationMode = OAuthOptions.AuthenticationMode;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType = OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType;
        OAuthBearerOptions.Description = OAuthOptions.Description;

        OAuthBearerOptions.Provider = new CustomBearerAuthenticationProvider();
        OAuthBearerOptions.SystemClock = OAuthOptions.SystemClock;

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        }
```