# How to return bearer token from HttpresponseMessage Asp.net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

How can I return token from web api so that I can set cookie of that token in javascript?
In this way I am generating token

```
   [Route("api/agency/login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage loginApi([FromBody] Users UserObj)
    {
           var tokanObj = method.AccessToken(UserObj.username, UserObj.Password, "password");

   //How to return this token ??
    }
```

Comment: What web api version are you using (.net core or Web Api 2 with full .net framework)?

Comment: Asp.net web api2

Comment: Change from HttpResponseMessage to String (or whatever type the token object is), and return tokenObj directly

Comment: What is tokenObj type ?

Comment: object  type is var

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [StringContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) ?

```
return new HttpResponseMessage( HttpStatusCode.OK ) 
{
    Content =  new StringContent( "Your token here" ) 
};
```

Comment: But can I set this token as cookie in javascript using sessionstorage?

Comment: Of course you can. Take a look at this example 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769422/net-web-api-2-owin-bearer-token-authentication?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider including the token as a cookie in the response

```
[Route("api/agency/login")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage loginApi([FromBody] Users UserObj) {
    var tokanObj = method.AccessToken(UserObj.username, UserObj.Password, "password");

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    //use what every you want as the key for the cookie
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("auth_token_key", tokenObj);

    //...set cookie values as needed

    response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });

    return response;
}
```